# Defining classes in an ontology

Tags: ontology

I am very new to creating ontologies, and I'm trying to make one for a club and society section of a website only using a few classes.

This is my structure so far (classes then indented for sub classes).

```
Person
    Member
    President
    Treasurer
Club/Society
    TypeOfClub
        Community
        CourseRelated
        FaithAndCulture
        HobbiesAndInterests
        MediaArtsAndMusic
        PoliticalAndActivism
Venue
    Booking
Location
```

I'm not 100% sure if what i'm doing is right. I just got rid of a lot of my sub classes realising that they were data type properties (number of members, joining fee) so now I have very few sub classes and can't think of what to add in their place.

I have venue as separate from location because I was trying to add in an rdf file that dealt with location in protoge (just to see how it would work).

Is there anything I should definitely add/get rid of with my class structure?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this documentation http://protege.stanford.edu/publications/ontology_development/ontology101-noy-mcguinness.html will help you to get a basic idea about Ontologies